# Calling Visual Studio method using powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script to call a method that's located in my Visual Studio (2010) solution. 
What is the syntax for calling, for example, a method like

```
public void CreateData(string s, int i)
```

?

Answer (score 6):

You can compile your class library project into a dll then load the dll using reflection in powershell. Here is an example:

c# code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void CreateData(string s, int i) {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

powershell code:

```
$lib = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\path\to\MyClass.dll")
$obj = new-object MyClass
$result = $obj.CreateData("s_value",5)
```

This code assumes that your class is called "MyClass". You may have to run set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned in powershell first.

Comment: You can use `LoadFrom` instead if you want to specify a relative path to a DLL

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build you C# class and use something like InvokeCSharp to call the CreateData method

Please see the link for a good example http://vincenth.net/blog/archive/2009/10/27/call-inline-c-from-powershell-with-invokecsharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would create a program like that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(args.Length > 1)
            CreateData(args[0], int.Parse(args[1]));
    }

    public static void CreateData(string s, int i)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\data.txt", 
              string.Format("This is some data:  s = {0}  i = {1}", s, i)); 
    }
}
```

And then after the program is compiled I have the executable "ConsoleApp.exe"

I launch the folowing  powershell script:

```
& "Path_Of_The_Program\ConsoleApp.exe" "MyText" 100
```

It successfully writes the data inside my file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can get my class to open using the syntax you gave me, but I can't get the specific method called. I tried going like myclass.cs/CreateData, but this didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to compile your class first and then launch the command with the .exe file path.  You can build your class using the csc command line utility ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx )