# Covert python or perl script to ASP or PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, asp-classic

I found a python or maybe perl(?) script, but I really don't want to install "all that" on Windows.  Is there any automated/easy way to convert this to run as classic ASP page, or as a PowerShell script?

The source script is at: https://github.com/artemdinaburg/bitsquat-script/blob/master/bitsquat.py

Comment: It's a python script. The clue is at the top of the file: `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - [no for powershell](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=convert%20perl%20to%20powershell), or else it would have shown on a google search, [yes](http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/6.0/PerlNET.html) for .net in general, which might remove the hassle of maintaining perl enviroments on target computers. This is the perl answer but i expect the python answer to be similar

Long answer - There shouldn't be, as the miniscule advantage of such a program will probably pale in comaprison of the complexity of such a program (which will entail interpreting the script and converting it to the foreign language, essentailly doing the job of an interpretor TWICE). I think a better question is whether it is even worth it.
Consider this - this script uses c style functions (gethostbyname) in a python script that you want to use in a .net enviroment under the powershell scripting language. Researching native powershell solutions in powershell libraries or going as far as using .net methods inside of powershell (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570011/calling-visual-studio-method-using-powershell)) will yield an easier to debug (and change in case of future needs) script than compiling or converting a script into a foreign language. tl;dr if you are going to use powershell, the best solution is to write powershell from the start. (or to not use powershell at all)

Answer (score 0):

No.

(I'm sure you could find a freelancer to do it for you though)