# Call class file method from NuGet package using Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to create a nuget package from my class libary. So far I managed to create and install the package in a test project, but I also want to create a package manager command. My `NuGet` package is created with the `NuGet Package Explorer`.

NuGet Package structure

[image: structure]

NuGet files content

init.ps1

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package) 
Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath MyNuGetCommands.psm1)
```

MyNuGetCommands.psm1

```
function Hello($name, $city) 
{ 
    Write-Host (‘Hello ‘ + $name + ‘. See you soon in ‘ + $city + ‘.’) 

    $lib = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("\\lib\EF.XML.dll")
    $obj = new-object Parser
    $result = $obj.UpdateXml()
}

Export-ModuleMember Hello

Register-TabExpansion ‘Hello’ @{  
‘name’ = { "MSFTees", "MVPs", "My friends" }; 
‘city’ = { "Redmond", "Seattle", "Bellevue", "Duvall" }; 
}
```

I found the Hello function on the net and it worked in my project so I thougt lets add some lines [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570011/calling-visual-studio-method-using-powershell) to call my C# method. When I call the Hello function in my test project I get this errors:

Error 1

> Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot find the network path. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070035)" At
>   \svr\redirectedfolders\Stage\my documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Test\packages\XML.EF.1.0.0\tools\MyNuGetCommands.psm1:5
>   char:43
>   +     $lib = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile <<<< ("\lib\EF.XML.dll")
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Error 2

> New-Object : Cannot find type [Parser]: make sure the assembly
>   containing this type is loaded. At
>   \svr\redirectedfolders\Stage\my documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Test\packages\XML.EF.1.0.0\tools\MyNuGetCommands.psm1:6
>   char:22
>   +     $obj = new-object <<<<  Parser
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Error 3

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   \svr\redirectedfolders\Stage\my documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Test\packages\XML.EF.1.0.0\tools\MyNuGetCommands.psm1:7
>   char:29
>   +     $result = $obj.UpdateXml <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (UpdateXml:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

So I think in the above errors `obj` is null but how can I fix this (I am not sure if LoadFile path is correct)? I did run  `set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned` in `Powershell`.

Parser.cs file structure in EF.XML.dll

```
public class Parser
{       
    public void UpdateXml()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

This is the code to I use to call the method from a .cs file (which works but I want to call this from my `Powershell Module`:

```
 var parser = new EF.XML.Parser();
 parser.UpdateXml();
```

Comment: `new-object Parser` -> `new-object EF.XML.Parser`

Comment: @PetSerAl I tried your suggestion, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: How about `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("\\lib\EF.XML.dll")`? Does it throw or not? If not, does it return `Assembly` object? Does path specified exactly like that `"\\lib\EF.XML.dll"`?

Comment: @PetSerAl I will try this tommorow when I continue working on this project and I will let you know what the results are.

Comment: @PetSerAl I also get an error for `LoadFile()`, the error is added to my post. I also tried `Add-Type -AssemblyName` but the dll is not found.

Comment: Try to specify full path to .dll file. `Add-Type -Path 'C:\Full\Path\To\EF.XML.dll'`.