# How do I call a public function in a .Net class library from powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, class-library

I have .Net c# class library (C:\path1\path2\Proj1.Web\bin\Proj1.Web.dll). The object browser shows the public function I want to call as follows

```
public void RunMe()
Member of Proj1.Web.Services.RunCustomServices
```

I am loading the assembly in powershell using

```
$asm=[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\path1\path2\Proj1.Web\bin\Proj1.Web.dll")
[Proj1.Web.Services.RunCustomServices]::RunMe()
```

> Method invocation failed because
>   [Proj1.Web.Services.RunCustomServices] doesn't contain a method named
>   'Runme'. At line:1 char:1
>   + [Proj1.Web.Services.RunCustomServices]::RunMe()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFoundPS C:\users\home> [Proj1.Web.Services.RunCustomServices]::RunMe() Method invocation
>   failed because [Proj1.Web.Services.RunCustomServices] doesn't contain
>   a method named 'RunMe'. At line:1 char:1
>   + [Proj1.Web.Services.RunCustomServices]::RunMe()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Step 1: look up `Add-Type` instead of using reflection directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Visual Studio method using powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570011/calling-visual-studio-method-using-powershell)

Comment: @Eris, care to explain why would that help in your opinion?

Comment: Nate, if your method is not static, which it is not, you need an instance of the class to call the method on. The syntax you are trying to use only works for static methods.

Comment: He needs to instantiate it @zespri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference .NET assemblies using PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell)

Comment: @Zespri, your comment helped me to resolve the issue. Thanks Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function is not `static` (or `Shared` in VB.Net terminology), you'll need to create an instance of the class to call the method on:

```
$RCSInstance = New-Object Proj1.Web.Services.RunCustomServices
$RCSInstance.RunMe()
```